# Fetch data from the 3rd party API to node.js server and make some processing

Tags: javascript, fetch, backend, sveltekit

I need my node.js-based application to get data from some 3rd party API (Rest) every x interval and do some things with fetched data.
Let’s say, the node.js server needs to fetch some data from API every 60 seconds and make records into a database (e.g. timestamp and value). What’s the best way to make it?

I need to achieve that functionality only using JS and Node (in my case it is SvelteKit framework over the node.js)

Comment: [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Answer (score -1):

Essentially you need to create a scheduled job in your nodejs app. You can probably make use of packages like `node-cron` to achieve that. It helps you provide a schedule and the function to be run on that schedule. Hope this helps.